# liveData with Coroutines and SavedStateHandle

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

This [answer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/715#issuecomment-5288178285) show us how can we use `liveData` in the repository to return a `LiveData` to `ViewModel` which the `View` will observe.
Now, what if we want to use `SavedStateHandle`? How can we transform the following code to use `liveData{}` from [LiveData-Ktx](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata)?

ViewModel:

```
private val _itemLiveData = stateHandle.getLiveData<MyItem>(KEY, MyItem())
val itemLiveData: LiveData<MyItem> = _itemLiveData

suspend fun nextPage() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val item = repoCall...
        stateHandle.set(KEY, item)
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
viewModel.itemLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
    lifecycleScope.launch {/*...update ui...*/}
})
```

Will we benefit from using `liveData{... emit()}`?

I can see 3 advantages of using `SavedStateHandle`:
1 - Restore your viewModel state
2 - It calls `.value()` for us when we use `stateHandle.set()`
3 - `stateHandle.getLiveData` helps us initialize the value (this is also helpful with `Data Binding` for example)

Comment: means you want to use stateHandle in activity right?

Comment: No, i'm using inside `ViewModel` https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateHandle and `stateHandle.set` calls `mutableLiveData.setValue(value);` for me which is fine. I wan't to know who to merge this with `liveData{}` or if there's no benefit in it while using `SavedStateHandle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this

```
class SomeViewModel(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
    repository:ItemsRepository) : ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        private const val PAGE_KEY = "page_key"
    }

    private val _page = MutableLiveData<PageId>(savedStateHandle.get(PAGE_KEY))

    private val _itemLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(_page) { pageId -> repository.getNextPage(pageId) }
    val itemLiveData: LiveData<MyItem> = _itemLiveData

    suspend fun nextPage(pageId: PageId) {
        _page.postValue(pageId)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        savedStateHandle.set(PAGE_KEY, _page.value)
    }
}


class ItemsRespository {

    fun getNextPage(pageId:PageId) = liveData() {
        ....
        emit(someData)
    }
}
```

Let me know if it helped you.
P.S.
PageId it can be number of current page or other any page identifier

Comment: Thanks for your response. What's the difference from what I have? Maybe I misinterpreted your answer. Where do you use https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata ?

Comment: it uses in repository call. I update my answer @GuilhE

Comment: I was betting on that but now I'm sure :) Thanks for your response! Your code makes sense but I can't test it right now. Did you test it?

Comment: No, i did`t test it code but I use same construction in own applications. And sametimes I append UseCase layer.

Comment: How to perform `SwitchMap` on itemLiveData?

Comment: @AlexanderKazantsev: There is a bug in your answer: You cannot save state in onCleared(), the system will just ignore anything you save there. Have a look here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62800028/how-to-lazily-save-viewmodels-savedstatehandle

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with `savedStateHandle`, the `get/set` methods feel like a mistake to me. The only one that is truly reliable is `getLiveData`, which you can combine into other LiveData using `Transformations.switchMap`.

If you use `getLiveData` with a type that is supported by `android.os.Bundle`, then you get state persistence out of the box through it. If you don't, then you'll just get crashes. `getLiveData` already returns a `MutableLiveData`, which is why it is not a good idea to handle `get/set` manually, you can vall `.value =` on the `MutableLiveData` from `SavedStateHandle` if need be.

Comment: Actually changing the `SavedStateHandle` by `.value=` makes sense, but why does `get/set` feel like a mistake, can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: I would think the idea of `handle.get()` is for values that don't change over time (for example values from the arguments bundle passed in as default args on handle init), but as it has a `set()` it clearly can change over time? But if it can change, then you want to be able to observe said changes, in which case you wanted a LiveData in the first place. So not sure where you'd ever want to use `handle.set()` instead of `handle.getLiveData()`.

Comment: I've replace this type of code: `stateHandle.set(KEY, value)` with `_MyLiveData.value = value` and it works just fine as expected. But when I was using `.set` the value overtime would change correctly because inside `set` it calls the `.value` for me. That said, wont `.value` or `.set` end up doing the same?