# How to lazily save ViewModel's SavedStateHandle?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-savedstate, viewmodel-savedstate

I have a screen that loads a bunch of requests and collects some data from the user on the same screen and an external WebView. Therefore, I have a ViewModel that contains these complex request objects (+ user input data). I need to persist this data through system-initiated process death, which `SavedStateHandle` is designed for. But I don't want to persist this data in a database because it is only relevant to the current user experience.

I have integrated my ViewModels with Hilt and received `SaveStateHandle`. Because I have some complex objects that are accessed/modified in several places in code I can't save them "on the go". I made them implement `Parcelable` and just wanted to save them at once. Unfortunately, ViewModels don't have a lifecycle method like `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Now, I have tried using `onCleared()` which sounded like a ok place to write to the handle. But it turns out that all `.set()` operations I perform there get lost (I'm testing this with developer options "Don't keep activities". When I use `.set()` elsewhere, it does work). Because the ViewModel is not tied to the lifecycle of a single fragment/activity but rather to a NavGraph I can't call in from their `onSaveInstanceState()`.

How/where can I properly persist my state in `SaveStateHandle`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is precisely the use case that the [Lifecycle 2.3.0-alpha03 release](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.3.0-alpha03) enables:

> `SavedStateHandle` now supports lazy serialization by allowing you to call `setSavedStateProvider()` for a given key, providing a `SavedStateProvider` that will get a callback to `saveState()` when the `SavedStateHandle` is asked to save its state. ([b/155106862](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155106862))

This allows you to handle any complex object and get a callback exactly when it needs to be saved.

```
var complexObject: ComplexObject? = null

init {
    // When using setSavedStateProvider, the underlying data is
    // stored as a Bundle, so to extract any previously saved value,
    // we get it out of the Bundle, if one exists
    val initialState: Bundle = savedStateHandle.get<Bundle?>("complexObject")
    if (initialState != null) {
        // Convert the previously saved Bundle to your ComplexObject
        // Here, it is a single Parcelable, so we'll just get it out of
        // the bundle
        complexObject = initialState.getParcelable("parcelable")
    }

    // Now to register our callback for when to save our object,
    // we use setSavedStateProvider()
    savedStateHandle.setSavedStateProvider("complexObject") {
        // This callback requires that you return a Bundle.
        // You can either add your Parcelable directly or
        // skip being Parcelable and add the fields to the Bundle directly
        // The key is that the logic here needs to match your
        // initialState logic above.
        Bundle().apply {
            putParcelable("parcelable", complexObject)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I seem to run into a bug here. When I'm opening a chrome custom tab via intent the savedStateProvider is properly called and everything works fine. But when the user uses the system "Overview button" to navigate to a different app the call is not made (though the `onSaveInstanceState` of my `MainActivity` is called). Any idea?

Comment: @A1m - you can [file an issue against Lifecycle](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=413132) with a sample project that reproduces your issue if you think there's a bug.

Comment: Personally I think this solution is ridiculous, why not just have an `override fun onSaveInstanceState()` method in the ViewModel? Or just support saving state in onCleared()? This is a huge oversight IMHO.

Comment: @Wess - You can certainly have your custom subclass of `ViewModel` have an `onSaveInstanceState()` method that hides all this logic, but `SavedStateHandle`, the class that actually controls all of the state saving, is purposefully usable from any `ViewModel` class (be it `ViewModel`, `AndroidViewModel`, or whatever other hierarchy of custom types you have). Note that `onCleared()` would never, ever be the appropriate place to save state - it is only called when your ViewModel is being permanently destroyed and never coming back.

Comment: @ianhanniballake that makes sense. But my suggestion is to rather provide an override method which signals to the `ViewModel` that it is going into a saved state soon and it should in that method save what it wants into the `SavedStateHandle`. I.o.w. similar to `override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle)` in `Fragments`, except it doesn't have parameter `Bundle` - its purpose is only to notify the `ViewModel` that it should save any state now. In my view something like this would be an easier and more familiar solution to developers to save state lazily, without creating subclasses.

Comment: @Wess see my answer to the question. reduces some of the code

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @ianhanniballake, you don't need to add any data to Bundle. You can still access Parcelable (or another data type) directly. The callback still works when it needs to save it.

```
init {
    savedStateHandle.setSavedStateProvider("") {
        savedStateHandle["complexState"] = state
        Bundle()
    }
}

var state by mutableStateOf(
    savedStateHandle["complexState"] ?: ComplexState()
)
```